# App is not getting listed in the google play store when going from Samsung S10 Android Phone

Tags: android, google-play, dpi

I have this odd issue with our app **"CyranoApp"**. This app has been in the google play store for since 4-years. But, unfortunately, this app is not listed in Google Playstore for these Samsung S10 phones.
I tried with multiple S10's and also did a factory reset. Still the same issue.
Later, I  removed the uses-feature, Compatible-Screen tags in the manifest files. **"This App is no longer compatible with your device"** is an Error Message showing in the Play Store. Kindly can help me to fix this issue.

My Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera2"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera2.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />

<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:exported="true"
    android:fullBackupOnly="false"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme"
    tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity">
    <meta-data
        android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
        android:value="false" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.max_aspect"
        android:value="2.1" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="preloaded_fonts"
        android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
    <service
        android:name="com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferService"
        android:enabled="true" />
    <service
        android:name=".s3uploads.UploadAudio"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
        android:stopWithTask="true" />
    <service
        android:name=".uploads.UploadVideo"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
        android:stopWithTask="true" />
    <service
        android:name=".uploads.UploadService"
        android:stopWithTask="false" />
    <service
        android:name=".services.RefreshToken"
        android:stopWithTask="false" />
    <service
        android:name=".services.AccessToken"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
        android:stopWithTask="true" />
    <receiver
        android:name="com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferNetworkLossHandler"
        tools:ignore="Instantiatable">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"
                tools:ignore="BatteryLife" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name=".receivers.RefreshTokenReciever"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:permission="normal"
        android:process=":remote" />
    <receiver
        android:name="com.app.receivers.IncomingCallReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <uses-library
        android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
        android:required="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Any Ideas? Please help.

Comment: Is it just S10, or also S9, S10e, S20 and other Samsung phones? That information could help. Also, you might want to post your manifest file here to help people get started. I don't do Android development but afaik that file is public and can be found in the apk file.

Comment: S10 and its newer versions. S20 i am not tested yet.